# Angular Material sorted table - How to align header text to right?

Tags: angular, sorting, header, angular-material

I am using an Angular Material table.

I can set column alignment to right.

HTML:

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
...
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    ...
```

CSS:

```css
.mat-column-position {
    text-align: right;
}
```

But when I am using the sorting feature, the column title is no longer aligned to the right:

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
...
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
    ...
```

I guess the issue is coming from the "sort" symbol.

Any thoughts?

[Live demo](https://mat-table-sorting.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 3):

You're right, it's coming from the sort symbol. One way to fix this would be using CSS to just change the [`direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) of that header from right to left:

```css
.mat-header-cell.mat-column-position {
    direction: rtl;
}

/* If you want the same default margin for the sort icon */
:host ::ng-deep .mat-header-cell.mat-column-symbol .mat-sort-header-arrow {
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Alternatively, you can set the `arrowPosition` attribute to `before` on a header cell to achieve the same result:

```html
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header arrowPosition="before">No.</th>
```

Comment: Additionnaly, it seems that using the arrowPosition attribute gives the same result.  (<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header arrowPosition='before'> No. </th>)

Comment: @Iznogood1 - nice, that is a better solution. I suggest you add your solution as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Additionnaly, it seems that using the arrowPosition attribute gives the same result.

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header arrowPosition='before'> No. </th>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to keep the sort arrow on the left side, I have found another solution:

```
::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-container {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Or alternatively put it in your global CSS file without `::ng-deep`:

```
.mat-sort-header-container {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scv8ng-xhjmva)